# Get screenshot of video with subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get a single frame of a video with ffmpeg including the the subtitles

> ffmpeg -ss 00:09:18 -i movie.mkv -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt -vframes 1
>   screenshot.png

The screenshot is outputting but the subtitles are not on the image.

I'm new to ffmpeg so if anyone could help me, that would be awesome!

Edit: Here's an example of output that I'm getting:

> ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the
>   FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu
>   5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 20160609   configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv   libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100   libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100   libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101   libavdevice    56.  4.100 /
>   56.  4.100   libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0   libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101   libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101   libpostproc    53.  3.100 /
>   53.  3.100 [aac @ 0xfe73c0] element type mismatch 3 != 0 [aac @ 0xfe73c0] element type mismatch 1 != 0
>       Last message repeated 1 times Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Community.S01E01.720p.5.1Ch.Web-DL.ReEnc-DeeJayAhmed.mkv':
>   Metadata:
>       encoder         : libebml v1.3.1 + libmatroska v1.4.2
>       creation_time   : 2015-10-16 19:35:27   Duration: 00:25:25.15, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1135 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         BPS             : 947111
>         BPS-eng         : 947111
>         DURATION        : 00:25:25.107000000
>         DURATION-eng    : 00:25:25.107000000
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 36566
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 36566
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 180555811
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 180555811
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
>       Metadata:
>         BPS             : 186250
>         BPS-eng         : 186250
>         DURATION        : 00:25:25.120000000
>         DURATION-eng    : 00:25:25.120000000
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 35745
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 35745
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 35506701
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 35506701
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES [Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x106ce60] Shaper: FriBidi
>   0.19.7 (SIMPLE) HarfBuzz-ng 1.0.1 (COMPLEX) [Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x106ce60] Using font provider fontconfig Output #0, image2, to
>   'screenshot.png':   Metadata:
>       encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
>       Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
>       Metadata:
>         BPS             : 947111
>         BPS-eng         : 947111
>         DURATION        : 00:25:25.107000000
>         DURATION-eng    : 00:25:25.107000000
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 36566
>         NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 36566
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 180555811
>         NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 180555811
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.4.0 ('A better way to fly') 32bit
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2015-10-16 19:35:27
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>         _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>         encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 png Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04
>   bitrate=N/A video:1109kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
>   global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -copyts option should be added.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:09:18 -copyts -i movie.mkv -vf subtitles=subtitles.srt -vframes 1 screenshot.png
```

The subtitles filter relies on input timestamps to know when to overlay subtitles, but a fast seek (`-ss` before `-i`) resets the timestamps of the trimmed portion before passing it along to the subtitles filter.

Comment: This did not work for me. I had the same output. I did try to do the same command but with -ss after the input and it worked. I would prefer to find a way to place -ss before the input because I heard there are performance increases.

Comment: Works here. Try with current version of ffmpeg.

Comment: I updated to the latest version and it worked! Thanks!