# FFmpeg - Screenshot/Snapshot with subtitles

Tags: video, ffmpeg

So, using FFmpeg, I'd like to know how to take a screenshot/snapshot of a single frame of a video on a specific time while having a separate subtitle file's line burned on the image. I'd like something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zI6A.jpg). The external subtitle is an *.ass* file (Advance SubStation Alpha), by the way, and as I mentioned, a separate file. The video itself has two subtitles softcoded, and I would prefer to not use those.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866614/get-screenshot-of-video-with-subtitles) and tried using a command based off the answer of the said question, but, to no avail.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:49.200 -copyts -i "path-to-video.mkv" -vf subtitles="path-to-subtitle.ass" -vframes 1 output.png
```

[And here's the output I get](https://pastebin.com/Tn92qJiK).

So, what should I do? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should write a single line to the image you want saved at a precise time. 
I'm not sure if it would work with .ass files.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:10:49.200 -i "path-to-video.mkv" -vf "[in]drawtext=fontfile=C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=0xffFFFF:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)-20:text='Your Text Here' [out]" -vframes 1 output.png
```